# How to show pagination range in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

Now my search page showing **24 Items in 3 Pages**

This is my controller code:

```
@post = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

This is my view:

```
<%= @post.total_entries %> Items in <%= @post.total_pages %> Pages
```

But I need to show **1 - 10 of 24 Items in 3 Pages** in the search first page, when I click second pagination then show **11 - 20 of 24 Items in 3 Pages**

How can I fix this?

Comment: which paginator are you using?

Comment: I'm using will_paginate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question it seems you are using `will_paginate`.You can use `page_entries_info(collection, options)` method will do this for you.Example

```
<%= page_entries_info @posts %>
#=> Displaying posts 6 - 12 of 26 in total
```

More info https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#page_entries_infocollection-options